# Websocket Server On Rails - Client Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

I want to listen to a websocket stream using the **faye-websocket-ruby gem**. But all I can find is standalone example scripts.

How can I integrate the following script in my current Rails application ?

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://www.example.com/')

  ws.on :open do |event|
    p [:open]
    ws.send('Hello, world!')
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    p [:message, event.data]
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    ws = nil
  end
}
```

Thanks !

EDIT : A basic use case would be to receive data from [Binance Websocket Streams](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md) and store in a database every trade received.

Comment: What is supposed to do?

Comment: Did you consider using [`iodine`](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) or [plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io/) for WebSockets? the plezi.io framework has specific [docs about Rails integration](http://www.plezi.io/docs/with_rack_app). I'm biased, since I'm the author, but I find them faster than Faye and easier to work with.

Comment: P.S. I assume you meant "Websocket Server", since you're asking about listening to incoming WebSocket connections. I suggest you update the question's title.